# Trying to send POST data through ajax in phonegap

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

i am using PushPlugin in my phonegap application. I want to send the registrationID to my server. I have one URL

```
'http://www.vbought.com/yukyuk/?regId=' +e.regid;
```

How can i send the data to the server.

Here is how my code looks likes.

```
case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    //alert("regID = " + e.regid);
                    //console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: '?regId='+e.regid,
                        url: 'http://www.vbought.com/yukyuk/',
                        success: function(data){
                        //console.log(data);
                            alert("Success Added");

                        },                
                        error: function(){
                            console.log(data);
                            alert('There was an error adding your comment');
                        }

                    });

                }
            break;
```

Do someone have any idea. How can i post data?

Thank you! (in advance)

Comment: What problem are you having? Is it giving an error?

Comment: no its not giving error, its not posting the data.

Comment: Try passing having your data in an object instead: `var data = { regId: e.regid };` and then your Ajax property would read `data: data,`